# How to Resync RAILS after a Table change (field insert and order)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

first: I am "playing/learning"

What I did was changeing the sequence of cols and adding a coloumn in my beloved sandbox table, directly with SQL

Standard steps

```
rename table to xxx_bac
create table xxx "with new order and a new field"
insert into xxx select cols_in_new_order from xxx_bac
drop Table xxx_bac
```

edit: (I try to better point out my question)

After this action I got errors like "Class String has not strftime() method", in fact, my datetime field mutated to a string field in my active record, and I use the strftime to convert it into a I18n format. Although the data was correct, the fact that it before was a datetime got lost.

It was easy to repair I just dropped the table, and run a rake db:migration. All is fine up and running

But what happened behind the scene? Where is the Information stored? In this (sandbox/playground) case its a sqlite3 Database, that has no datetime, so rails must store this information somewhere else. I want to know whats going on, where the things a 'remembered'

I am not asking how to use rake db migrations.

an other edit:

Imagine you have a ready database with lets say 100 tables, and now you want some of them use with active.* in rails. So how to import the table structure into rails?

Comment: Please read the guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Comment: You need to update schema.rb (I guess manually) to reflect new column order. That should help. I also see no real reason why anyone would do what you did.

Comment: @BenjaminSinclaire: i read it, twice, and like other rails guides, it like a cookbook, without information whats happening behind the scene.

Comment: @MichalSzyndel: For me it looks like schema.rb is generated. after a rake db:migrate (without any outstanding tasks) schema.rb looks like before, any manual changes whiped out.     so my question, where are these informations stored? I am working on a very special technical solution; and I am using the DB2 possibillites like recursive selects intensivly. In fact most of the application runs without any ActiveSomething. And second I am just curios, like a child.

Comment: Sorry but it's unclear. We don't know which environment you are using, what commands you type before the issue... well in fact we don't even know the issue precisely. You want help? You need to provide a clear question with step-by-step to reproduce, error messages, a relevant parts of codes when applicable. Otherwise: read the guides (yep) cause you certainly did something wrong and the guides explain how to do things right. Good luck

Comment: @BenjaminSinclaire: yes, my question is unclear, I try to better point out

Comment: If you're not using ActiveRecord or some other ORM designed for Rails, you're not really using Rails, and there's nothing to sync up. If you want Rails to sync with your db, you actually need to let Rails control your db through migrations, as mentioned earlier. As far as what's going on behind the scenes, I'm not sure any one person fully understands ActiveRecord.

Comment: Ok, from your comments I lost any hope that this can be resolved. I also have no idea what you are doing, I guess you have no idea as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for doesn't exist - there's no syncing to do after a schema change.

Activerecord does make certain assumptions, for example that table names are the pluralized version of the class name and that there is a primary key called id. If you change that then you need to tell it (eg by using `self.table_name = "foo"` in the corresponding class)

In addition your code (whether written by you or generated) will make some assumptions about the data. For example if you use the scaffold generator then it would generate views according to the type information you have given it (eg using `strftime` to format a date on a show page or using a checkbox as the edit control for a boolean attribute).

There's no central repository of this type information though (unless you count schema.rb, but that is not used at application runtime - it is used for creating new databases from scratch and things like that)